# UITableView Reload Data

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I use UITableView to show the informations get for server. Create the connection in viewWillAppear: method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//Create connection
}
```

And i put the received data into array : `NSSArray *dataFromServer:`

Then i want to show the data on each cell (some NSString object).

As the connection was release, i call `[self.tableView reloadData]` , but can't work.

So i'd like to know, how to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection needs time to load data. So the correct is load the UI -> loading the data -> refresh the UI. So when the view was load, add the activityView is the good choice. And when the data finish loading, remove the activityView, and call [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: thank you, Pranav Singh. Acutally i want to edit it. But i edited more than 5 today already.

Answer (score 0):

The connection needs time to load data. So the correct is load the UI -> loading the data -> refresh the UI. So when the view was load, add the activityView is the good choice. And when the data finish loading, remove the activityView, and call  `[self.tableView reloadData];`